# MATLAB statistics with uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, matlab

I have created a random uniform distribution with values between $5$ and $6.5$. I have also found the mean. I am stuck on a problem that asks how many values are higher than the mean.

How would I do this? I've tried the `length(find(x))` function but it did not work. help please?

```
   pd=makedist('Uniform','Lower',5,'Upper',6.5)
   average_height=mean(pd) 
   length(find(pd>5.75))`
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see  that you have specified how many observations
you have chosen at random from $Unif(5, 6.5).$ So it is not
clear what you are trying to do or what you are asking.

This is a symmetrical distribution with mean and median 5.75.
About half of your observations should exceed 5.75.

With `m = 10^6` observations, we have the following simulation in R.

```
 m  = 10^6;  x = runif(m, 5, 6.5)
 mean(x);  median(x)
 ## 5.750394
 ## 5.749982
 sum(x > 5.75)
 ## 499985
```

The vector `x > 5.75` is logical, having element `TRUE` for
values of x greater than 5.75, and `FALSE` otherwise.
The sum of a logical vector treats each `TRUE` as a 1
and each `FALSE` as a 0. Thus the last statement provides a count of the observations
exceeding 5.75.